# Additional white space between the "deleted" and "inserted" sides of the edit review screen

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues

When editing a review, it can be a little tough to visually separate the old and new versions, if the lengths of words/sentences and how they wrap is just so.

Here's an edit I opened directly while viewing a recent question. There's a background-color difference between the two sides, but it's pretty faint, and I tend to not even notice it.

[image: the text is sooo close]

Here's another, from the "reopen" queue:

[image: reopen queue]

This one, from the "suggested edit" queue, happens to have words that wrap just right, so there's extra space between the current version and suggested edit.

[image: suggested edit queue]

If some white-space, even just 15 or 20 px, could be added between the "deleted" and "inserted" sides of an edit, I think it may help readability.

[image: a little extra white space]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have made the suggested change. The margin between the right and left diff sections has been increased from 10px to 30px. This is live now.

Comment: This change appears to be causing the text in the right diff section to occasionally [get cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf0hf.png). Since the container has a fixed width, the right pane now effectively has 20px less of horizontal room than it used to.

Comment: @IronFlare thanks for bringing that to my attention. Should be fixed now as well.