# Stack Overflow vs. Stack Overflow - What can we as a community do to improve the relationship with the company that backs us?

Tags: discussion, users, stack-exchange, behavior

The relationship between us, the community, and the company is far from perfect. Yet we depend on each other:

Stack Overflow (the community) would not exist without Stack Overflow (the company) providing infrastructure, maintenance, development, and last but (definitely) not least: Community Managers that help us handling extraordinary cases.

Stack Overflow (the company) depends on Stack Overflow (the community) to provide great (okay, let's say "good") answers to questions, which is the only lasting asset Stack Overflow has.

Yet the relationship between the two sides of this site has gone worse, or at least, it definitely needs improvement. [Employees fear Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#comment1030131_314348), and that [has its reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366705/5260024).

On the other hand, the community [doesn't feel heard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386324/the-stack-overflow-i-wish-to-build-and-participate-in-is-no-longer-supported). There are a lot of feature requests aging away, even trivial ones. It feels as if the company ignores us, even if [that's not true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live).

I think one of the reasons for all of this is that Stack Overflow (the company) has added more products to it's portfolio (Jobs, Business, ...). While it makes sense for the company to offer these products (the codebase / userbase is already there), it makes "the community" one of many customers that needs to be supported. We have to accept that.

Let's stop blaming the other side for not listening. Let's stop all those [strikes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/declaring-a-review-strike-until-efficiency-improvements-are-implemented), [accusations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376430/5260024), and snarky comments towards the company that backs us.

Lets turn all that negative energy, all that frustration that bottled up over years and turn it into positive one!

Let's start with us. If we act more supportive towards the company, the company might be more willing to support us more. Let's form a union again - one Stack Overflow.

So what can we do to support the company? (In revenue, workforce, or words?)

How do we make sure that points raised by the commuity arrive at the site?

How can we be more friendly (aka. productive) towards employees?

Let's talk!

(For sure every word I wrote is up to discussion too)

Comment: The company is no longer interested in the opinion of the loud minority that is Meta. We can either accept that and stay around, or move on. I'm in the process of moving on.

Comment: I won't stop you, thats your personal decision. I'll stay and try to do my best to improve the situation.

Comment: Relationship implies a two-way street....i see very little reciprocity here.

Comment: When reading the title I thought: "Wow, great idea to reconcile the sides", but at the end of read, you're mostly asking us to "give the other cheek" and accept being ignored, your example of company listening to us is one half baked (there's far much to add ot it, per tag templates, etc.) thing which hasn't improved in a visible manner the influx from a large amount of feature request not getting any feedback.

Comment: Well someone has to make the first step.

Comment: @JonasWilms Then what about SO poking at the dozen of FR open for years as a first step ?

Comment: That's the point... every time the community takes a step towards SE.... SE takes a step backwards with it's hands over it's ears.

Comment: Okay, then what do you suggest @tensibai ? What should we do instead? Wait? Giving up? That really makes things better.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: SO has all power to break this bad cycle by giving proof of good faith by implementing some not really complex and fairly sensible feature requests opened for years, at this point to build back the confidence of the community into SO, they NEED to make this first step.

Comment: We also do have the power to brake that vicious circle ... But we don't. We wait for SO to do so...

Comment: @JonasWilms We have power to try, I'll give you that, but what makes you think we have the power to succeed? Blind faith isn't something I'm particularly interested in at this point

Comment: @JonasWilms How so ? asking once again the same FR ? Asking about if they're planned somewhere in the future ? Stopping giving disapproval feedback of what is done and being silent, this is mostly giving up. I'm tempted to return the question: what do you think should be done toward the latest "New Homepage" to be supportive of it ?

Comment: @Clive it is in the companies interest to be supported by the community. If were not heard again, then, well, then I'm giving up too

Comment: @JonasWilms your fundamental problem is *Let's start with us*, we're not a single coordinated entity capable of starting anything. The company is. It won't work that way, unless you plan on somehow organizing thousands of users to do that, users over which you have no leverage and who have no common interest to appeal to you can use to sway them.

Comment: The company is called "Stack Exchange", by the way.

Comment: @cerbrus I know, but the "two sides of a medal" thing worked better that way

Comment: @Magisch we are already organizing thousands of users answering millions of questions ... "appeal to you" ... I'm obviously not the right person for that, and thats not what I was trying to say with "Let's start with us" - I meant to address everyone personally there, not "us" as an "organized community that has one common sense"

Comment: The SO community is not a customer, it's an asset that's part of the company's product. And at this point, this asset is extremely fed up.

Comment: @JonasWilms You're making the same mistake as people believing conspiracy theories often do. What people here do is of nerf-herding character at best. When interests and motivations converge, as they do on SO, no coordination is necessary, and substantial coordination on this scale would be completly unfeasible.

Comment: @Magisch I'm sorry, but I reread your comment a few times and still can't grasp the meaning. Could you maybe rephrase it?

Comment: @JonasWilms People gravitate towards what they want. The SO Q/A engine gives people a way to express a want (helping people, building a knowledge library) in a painless or less painful way then otherwise. That is how we are "organizing thousands of people answering millions of questions". Nobody is sitting behind a desk somewhere with "Question Answering Coordinator Esq." written on it, nor does anyone need to. In communities of such a scale as SE, the only real way to drive large scale user behavior is via incentives and systems. No amount of appealing on meta has a chance of making a dent.

Comment: @Magisch an example: I'm answering a lot of questions on my mobile phone while travelling, but I don't do reviews there as the review page doesn't work there. I do however know a bit of HTML, CSS and JS, so I could tackle the problem myself. I could then submit that request to "the community"  in the form of a meta post, and if it reaches a certain amount of upvotes I think one could say that the community supports that, and then it could be rolled out

Comment: @JonasWilms: There are a bazillion of feature requests that already include the required code to implement said request. The problem here is that those feature requests apparently don't have any priority.

Comment: @Cerbrus still someone has to add / test that. If the frontend would be open-sourced ...

Comment: Getting community support for feature requests isn't hard; what is, though, is convincing SE to implement it.  As time as moved on, [we're being heard less and less](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#314348).  Trying to set developer priority by community vote is laudable, but about as effective as governments promising to respond to petitions that get over a certain number of signatures.

Comment: @fbueckert ever been to switzerland? ;)

Comment: Can't say that I have; been close, though.  Do they work differently than most governments?

Comment: @fbueckert they really like their referendums :)

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the info; sounds like a more active version of democracy.  Considering the cynicism and jadedness we have here in North America towards politics, it'd be somewhat refreshing to have a better voice in government.

Comment: @fbueckert: On the other hand, there is such a thing as too many referendums... There are matters "the people" really have no business voting on.

Comment: @Cerbrus I feel like it'd be a balance; right now, it feels like most citizens have absolutely no voice, so opening it up would feel empowering at first, until it got to be too much, and participation would dwindle.  It does raise the risk of more things like Brexit, where FUD is very much a problem.  I don't know of a good way to mitigate that, but I think there's a benefit to having more a voice.

Comment: @fbueckert switzerland has a kind of balanced thing for that,they love their referendums, but mostly they're to oppose a decision/law, too much to say in a comment so better give a link :) https://www.ch.ch/en/demokratie/political-rights/referendum/

Comment: *"Let's stop blaming the other side for not listening. Let's stop all those strikes, accusations and snarky comments"* - yes! *"towards the company that backs us"* - there you lost me, it is more us that backs the company.  *"So what can we do to support the company? (in revenue, workforce, or words?)"* - not the first two, that's for paid employees to worry about. We can help to build up the brand, though. As long as we get some clear guidelines on how to do that of course.

Answer (score 38):

#### Negotiation

Look, we know what SO the company wants.

For both commercial and ideological reasons, they want to dramatically increase the number of new users to join and participate in the community. In particular, they are trying to rebrand themselves as the platform for “anyone who codes”. They want a larger base of committed, returning users, and they believe the way to do that is to increase the TAM, which entails removing barriers to entry.

And we also know exactly what we can do to give them what they want: downvote less, closevote less, close-as-duplicate less, comment less. Answer more, handhold more, spoonfeed more. Expect less of askers, expect less basic knowledge, expect less effort. Donate more time, donate more expertise, donate more goodwill.

That is: we know exactly what SE, Inc. wants and how to give it to them. It’s not a mystery and it’s not hard. *That’s not the problem*.

#### Diplomacy

The problem is that, broadly speaking, *we don’t want to do that*.

In analogy to SE, Inc’s commercial motivations, people here who are volunteering their time and expertise *want to get something out of it, too*. Spoonfeeding every first year programmer whose first instinct is to ask on SO instead of googling is not rewarding.

In analogy with SE, Inc’s ideological commitments, we have our own, centered around the creation and curation of a clear, general, longlived, and vast library of reusable information for the good of everyone. Making the internet a better place. Obsoleting the old and broken model of forums where anyone asks anything and it devolves into endless discussion, unresolvable noise, obliterating all signal.

#### Extension by other means

And etc, etc, same old story.

If we want to restore goodwill, good faith, and good communication between the parties, both parties have to come to the table and reach alignment on the fundamental *vision*.

I don’t know what to concretely recommend to advance that goal, because the bridges to Meta, as a consensus-building platform, have been, as you observed, burned. This isn’t “the table” anymore.

Comment: [Case in point.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387137/2562182)

Answer (score 20):

> So what can we do to support the company? (in revenue, workforce, or words?)

Post feature requests, bug reports and other discussions on Meta. Review. Keep the site's content as high quality as possible.

The problem is that the available tools aren't sufficient, and that feature requests seemingly go ignored for months, or even years.

> How do we make sure that points raised by the commuity arrive at the site?

Did you mean: *"How do we make sure the points raised arrive at those in charge?"*
By having them read Meta. We can't force them to do so, that's up to them.

> How can we be more friendly (aka. productive) towards employees?

Friendlyness and productiveness aren't related. In my experience, they're almost mutually exclusive.

A productive / efficient bug report isn't "friendly". It's factual.

---

In the end, it's up to SE to start listening to "the people", but that point has been discussed ad nauseam already, so I'll refrain from doing so here.

Answer (score 20):

When reading the title I thought: "Wow, great idea to reconcile the sides", but at the end of read, you're mostly asking us to "give the other cheek" and accept being ignored.

The inflexion point for me has been your example of Stack Exchange the company listening to us. The ask wizard is really a small step which hasn't improved in a visible manner the quality of new questions. Moreover it is unfisnished, there's been request to improve it from the first template, having per tag templates with their specificity for example, and a lot more I don't remember.

In the same time there's been a lot of efforts puts elsewhere, but not on even acknowledging feature requests or trying to plan them.

So in my point of view, while your query sounds a really a good idea, Stack Exchange **has** and **need** to make the first step toward us. Implementing some feature requests  which are far from complex and pretty straighforward <strike>like [Additional white space between the “deleted” and “inserted” sides of the edit review screen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288023/additional-white-space-between-the-deleted-and-inserted-sides-of-the-edit-re) (selected because it really drives the point) would be a first start.</strike> [Now done, per comment I'll direct other I stumble on by mail]

I can't imagine people caring to be on meta are here purely to be snarky or vindicative, but that's a consequence of how we've been considered for the last 3 or 4 years.

So to address your questions, I'm pretty sure that if Stack Exchange really wish it, they can tackle some feature requests, deny some others because too complex or too harsh for new users if they feel so and trust could come back and things would settle.

Comment: I heard a great interpretation of what was meant by, "turn the other cheek".  The examples provided weren't so much to just roll over and take it, but created a public display to defy and embarrass the antagonist.  I'm no expert at all, but that sounded like a novel perspective on the act.

Comment: @fbueckert That's mostly my point here, I think the post ask for it but that doing it won't achieve any embarrassment of Stack Exchange and just get us another slap (in form of requests being ignored/dismissed). Maybe I could have worded that more clearly, if you have an idea feel free to edit and I'll roll back if it doesn't match what I mean :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong; I agree with your answer.  It was more a comment on using social pressure to enact change.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any way to apply any leverage to get the kind of change we need.  I'd say Twitter, but wading into that sludge doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: @fbueckert I have misinterpreted your first comment then :) I'm not very confident things will move anytime soon unless SE shows a will in that way

Comment: @fbueckert The magic isn’t in Twitter, the magic is in visibility and in touching a particular wound that SE finds painful. April is a high-visibility social justice advocate, and her tweets and retweets shine a very bright light on what SE considers its greatest PR vulnerability. Tweeting a complaint about SO when you’re not *both* prominent *and* addressing a social justice concern will be as effective as posting on a Meta. The problem as I said in my answer is a misalignment of vision, not a choice of platform. I’m waiting for someone (not me) to launch an SE competitor w/ our vision.

Comment: @Tensibai I have gone ahead and implemented the [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288023/51) that you linked above. I hear the feelings going on here and can empathize with y'all very much. I recently joined the Community Dev team, and I can tell you that there is lots being planned that will hopefully help folks to feel more heard, but I can't speak to any particulars here. That said, if there are more old Feature Requests like this - impactful yet not too complex - please email me a link and I will see what I can do. Thanks for bringing this to our attention again.

Comment: @YaakovEllis first: thanks :) Second: genuine question: are the feature requests surfaced on meta gathered into an internal backlog or is there only meta and the feature-request tag ?

Comment: @YaakovEllis I think checking all the FR tagged status-review could be a good start, there's 34 actually, thoose with years of review status sounds like they have been forgotten: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request%20status-review?sort=MostVotes&edited=true Out of that (FR without mod tag) I found a few more like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349861/change-default-bounty-reason and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290026/markdown-editor-indent-and-outdent-functionality (the second one may need to rehash talk about it)

Comment: Forgot to say: when I say checking, I mean check they're not done or are still relevant, maybe just tag them complete, denied or no-repro, there's a least [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326004/can-you-please-add-underlines-to-hyperlinks) which I think is completed in actual UI

Comment: @Tensibai in addition to meta, they are gathered into an internal tool that we use for triage. We are right now trying to improve this process to increase our responsiveness and as you point out, tag requests as completed/denied/no-repro when appropriate.

Answer (score 17):

Others pretty much covered my thoughts however, I wanted to address a comment of yours, which truth be told, annoyed me (maybe more than it should've):

> Well someone has to make the first step.

First steps?

Are you serious?

[@Zoe's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe) answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385143/2263631) brilliantly outlines, well, pretty much all of it.

Curators are ***still*** actively taking steps (even after all the nonsense):

- ***Still*** suggesting features to improve the site and its current state, ***even though*** they know that these suggestions probably won't be implemented because SO has drifted so far off course from where it began (based on the track record of the last couple of years)
- ***Still*** giving feedback when presented with the option to, ***even though*** recently features have been implemented without consultation and then people feel "unwelcomed" on meta when harsh criticism is provided
- ***Still*** keeping on top of queues, ***even though*** management doesn't seem to care about the quality of the content

Maybe I'm wrong. Maybe SO does care. But, simply put, **actions speak louder than words**.

Yet:

- Curators were vilified with the "unwelcoming" nonsense
- Barraged with the "we need to be more inclusive" agenda
- Tarred as elitist/sexist/racist/`<other-term-here>`
- ...?

When SO came up with the "unwelcoming" stuff, they could've said that there are problems on either side but no, they blamed one side. No mention of the terrible content that gets cleaned up by the community or trying to explain to new users that terrible content ***will*** be down-voted/closed and that this shouldn't be taken personally. No blog post. No tweet. Not even a meta post. How do you think people would feel who've given years and years to build this site?

I've said this before and I'll say it again, each time curators raise these issues on meta, one of two things happen:

- Either it gets completely ignored from an official response and the community suggests a bunch of things and everyone walks away as though something amazing has been accomplished only to return back to another version of this post in a couple of months. Rinse and repeat. (Your post is just another version of existing posts trying to rally everyone back together)
- Or, SO will give us a canned response: '*We know we've been bad at communicating and we're working on it[...]*' yada yada and ***still***, nothing will come from it.

Maybe it's time to come to term with the "new" SO and those who don't like it, well, should just jump ship. If things were gonna change, they'd have done so a while back. It was fun while it lasted though.

<sub>It might seem as though I'm being hyperbolic but quite a few high rep users have already nuked their accounts...</sub>

Comment: speaking of SO (the company) actions, per my reading of [features change log](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/165773) they started addressing some of core users needs in first 6-7 months of 2019. I think it's too early to say that _Era of Great Negligence_ of [2016-2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314348/165773) is over but the trend looks rather promising (keeping fingers crossed)

Comment: I was with you until you rallied everyone to jump the ship. I'll wait until the ship jumps me. Or until it jumps the shark. Feel free to argue the latter has already happened, but until SE starts removing curation features because they "reduce user participation", there's hope.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I wasn't advocating for everyone to jump ship at all: '*Maybe it's time to come to term with the "new" SO **and those who don't like it**, well, should just jump ship.*'. It was mainly aimed at those who can't tolerate, at all, this new direction of SO.

Answer (score 5):

Jeff Attwood lists [4 ways that Stack Exchange makes money](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79448/343810) (mostly, advertising, SO for Teams, and Stack Overflow Jobs). That being said, here's a very central question: who does Stack Exchange regard as the actual customer? Who *should* they regard as the actual customer? Is it high-rep users who generate a of the answers, people who moderate the site to keep it clean, casual readers who look at ads, frequent readers who visit the site a lot [but might see fewer ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)? A few other possibilities that I can think of:

- Companies who buy ad space
- Companies that post jobs
- People looking for jobs that use the job site
- New users and/or infrequent users

That brings us to the flaw in your central thesis:

> If we act more supportive towards the company, the company might be more willing to support us more.

If by "we," you mean "the company's customers" (whoever they are), then why should we have to "support" them hoping that they'll support us in return?

Now, to return to the question of who the customers are. Most of the ways that they could make money off of the main site involves having people visit the site. No traffic, no revenue - lots of traffic, lots of revenue. In other words, everyone who either visits the site - or makes other people more likely to visit the site - is the customer.

Here's the key: "Makes other people more likely to visit the site" includes people who post questions, people who post answers, and people who moderate the site. If any of those activities didn't take place, or took place at a much lower rate than they do now, there would probably be considerably less traffic. If you had to wade through 50 feet of "me too!" answers and follow-up questions posted as answers in order to get your answer (like you used to have to on some other programming forums), if no one was asking questions that were relevant to your problem, or if most of the questions didn't have answers, odds are you would be much less likely to visit the site. And, just like that - much less traffic, much less revenue.

At this point, I've contributed 466 answers and 42 questions to Stack Overflow main site, 179 questions and 68 answers on [Literature.se](https://literature.stackexchange.com), and 29 questions and 22 answers on [SciFi.se](https://scifi.stackexchange.com), just to name a few. (In fact, I have content on 38 separate SE sites, accounting for 1000 main-site posts and several hundred Meta posts network-wide). I also have 5 gold badges for reviewing on Stack Overflow, and regularly use the site to look for information on problems I'm having. My main point in bringing that up is is to say that, if I'm not one of their customers, I'm not sure who is. That being said: isn't it their responsibility to support me? After all, I'm presumably a major source of revenue for them, so I'm already supporting them.

Actually, a really good follow-up on this is "who, exactly, is the customer?"

By the same token, though, they're offering me a valuable product at no direct cost to me, one that has benefited me enormously. I can't even remember how many times I've been helped by information I've found on Stack Exchange sites. That being said, I have a vested interest in Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange being the best it can be. So it's absolutely in my best interest to treat this as a partnership of sorts, but it's also important to remember that I'm ultimately the customer.

Comment: Customers pay money. You’re not a customer, you’re a user. 100% guaranteed their board decks include separate slide and sections covering “user growth” and “customer growth”.

Comment: @DanBron My content is generating traffic (and, therefore, revenue) for the company. The distinction between me performing actions that directly cause them to get revenue and me actually paying them myself seems like semantics in this case.

Comment: @DanBron Besides, they're not paying me to write content for them, even though their own statistics show my posts on my top 5 sites alone reaching 744k users (and that's excluding my Meta posts and the other 35 sites I participate in, which adds up to several hundred thousand more reached). The fact that I post well-received content here [arguably constitutes a payment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/are-the-qa-posted-on-stack-exchange-websites-valuable-consideration).

Answer (score -3):

Its not about turning the other cheek. Its about disagreeing constructively.

A lot of the mess-ups the company's done in the past have been stuff we *kept* warning them about, and happened anyway. So the occasional reminder is good.

On the other hand - its *essential* to both pick our battles and have the opening not to fight at all. If there's a chance to get a change pushed through, it makes a lot more sense to have neutral tone. I've occasionally *tactically* used a less neutral tone, but a lot of meta seems combative.

From the twitter s*itstorm, mods ended up getting a way to get a CM to check out issues on social media. We're unlikely to have another incident like what that resulted.

So, here's a thing. If SO *didn't* care about existing users, strikes, and yelling and accusations wouldn't work. Y'all are just wasting your time then. You're just dead weight who don't meet what SO's supposed to be today. Its a really difficult starting point. Only if there's *any* chance of convincing people there's a point.

That said, *lots* of folks who work at SO actually have a attachment to the network. They know people who know people who make the decisions.

The people who work here are only human - and I don't think intentionally shedding experienced users is is a goal. There's been *many* communications missteps (and a lot of work to fixing *years* of focus on things that never quite went to plan).

So - its perfectly cool to take TPTB to task on specific *critical* issues, I've personally had great luck in a few cases. That said, on meta, downvotes are a *blunt instrument*. They communicate naught but disagreement. That -160 is *scary* but doesn't really communicate very much.

Post answers - sometimes scathing ones. They tell what *exactly* is wrong - especially if you focus on the *problem* and not the people, and upvotes on those are less blunt. They *communicate* what folks want.

I actually get folks fearing meta. Meta is *different*. Its also a key tool if you want to engage with the users on the site. You can't fear your tools if you're going to use them. You can't get a community to respect you if they don't *know* you, and no one's going to know someone you don't talk to. This feels like a bug.

So, its gotta work both ways. The company's got to see the value in the community. Some days, they seem to more than others. Folks have also got to figure out the best ways to be heard, and not be considered, well cranks.

Comment: I don't believe that strikes wouldn't work at all. These don't work only as long as they target stuff considered harmless for the company (eg efficiency of review queues). But if a strike (involving even diamond mods) happens on something like [meta-tag:welcoming] effort (or some other stuff driven by politics / marketing), it could be quite difficult for them to handle. Gap between company and core community is probably not (yet) wide enough for something like that to happen but still, this isn't something worth ignoring

Answer (score -3):

### Appoint an ambassador.

One individual, selected by the Stack Overflow community, would become the community's ambassador to Stack Exchange the company.

The ambassador would receive input from the community -- various perspectives, ideas, and recommendations -- to present to Stack Exchange employees who are in a position to act on this input.

As a single point of contact, having an ambassador would be a more efficient way to communicate; and as a specialist in diplomacy, the ambassador could be more persuasive -- and more pleasant for company employees to interact with than reading the often negative feedback on Meta.

To choose an individual for the role, the ambassador could be elected by the community in a similar fashion to the way moderators are currently elected.

Comment: If you don't like this proposal, why not?