# What should I do when a user keeps changing their question expecting me to change my answer to match?

Tags: discussion, help-vampire

Today I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992192/why-does-attachment-do-not-send-with-this-code/56993076#56993076)  which I answered.

The person clearly couldn't use PowerShell. I've provided three times an answer to the question updating the code, only to see the exact same code I've written in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004816/how-do-i-make-this-code-to-send-emails-to-many-recipients#comment100544621_57004816) by another user.

Well my question is: **What should I do?**

I'm pissed because someone is trying to get their code written by the community.
As well as I'm mad that this side is used for that intend (not marked as an correct answer). I get the feeling the person is abusing this site and abusing others to be their code monkeys.

Is there an possibility to flag such behavior?

Comment: If you think it's the **same** question...flag it as a duplicate. If it's not Downvote it.

Comment: First: vote to close the second as a dupe of the first. Second: downvote either or both as lacking research and a MVCE. Third: shrug and walk away, don’t let this guy steal or time or joy. Fourth, and most important: the next time you see a Q having the same characteristics as (1) or (2), ie someone who has no idea what he’s doing, **don’t answer**, don’t feed the bears. They’ll just come back bigger, hungrier, and now demanding food.

Comment: Also - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Comment: @Paulie_D I can't flag it as the same question because it wasn't marked as an right answer

Comment: Bet you can now it has an upvote! ☺

Comment: @Dan Bron Indeed don't feed the beast. But it feels dirty that someone is doint this with mutiple acc to let the code be written by others. And that is what bothers me.

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you, I flagged it. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @Paulie_D didn't know it was called help-vampire ^^

Comment: This sort of behaviour is unfortunately common.  You can try to teach people, but often, they don't want to learn; just transfer the code, and move on.  You can take solace in the fact that such people will quickly be question banned, and lose any ability to get more help.

Comment: @fbueckert Yes sure, but only watching how people do that can't be an option or?
The last question on the original post was because of encoding. Approx within 24h there will be a new acc and the followup question as a new question. I'd rather mark the follow up as an ```help-vampire``` then watch someone else answer that and so on.

Comment: Sure, we can mark such people as help vampires....but it doesn't do anything to change their behaviour.  SO has systems to prevent users from using multiple accounts to bypass the question ban; they can create new accounts, but eventually, the system gets wise and prevents the whole block from interacting with the site.

Comment: @gnat I'd say my question goes in the same direction. What kinda sucks is that my answer from question 1 was taken in question 2 as example code of what he has so far. Like the discribe "chameleon" only with 2 sperate questions and accounts.

Answer (score 4):

> only to see the exact same code I've written in another question by another user.

If you see a question with the same code as another question asking the same thing, flag (or vote, at 3k+ reputation) the question as a duplicate of the first one.

> What should I do?

I have been exactly where you are multiple times before. You should downvote such questions for not being clear or including enough prior research, and walk away. Especially if you are getting upset, as you say. There are always going to be other questions to answer where the asker won't rewrite their question five times over.

If a user is changing their question over and over again, you can leave a comment saying that that's not recommended, and in fact *not allowed* if the change invalidates an existing answer (such as yours).

But regardless, if it's starting to annoy you or frustrate you, the best course of action is to remove yourself.

---

If what OP is *really* wanting is truly so unclear that you can't guess at what the ultimate answer would be, you can flag the question for closure as "Unclear what you're asking". At 3,000 reputation, this option turns into a vote to close rather than a flag.

Regarding your concern about the *user*, there's no option to make any user-based note. Moderators have that ability, but it's private (for obvious reasons). However, the behavior you've described isn't really actionable by moderators thus far.

Comment: The walkway approach is sounding better and better. But as in the example: You have someone who asks a question and you answer it. Within 24h there is a followup question (another question) with the provided answer from the first question, it's kinda not a duplicate. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Aguestwho'scalledRedd That's a valid method and is actually encouraged. The alternative is the person asking you in comments under your first answer all of these followup questions, or the scenario you're experiencing, where they keep editing their question based on your answer revisions, neither of which is preferred.

Comment: @Aguestwho'scalledRedd If the new question with your code is by a user with a different account, you *could* flag the new question for moderators and describe your suspicion *in detail*. It could be a case of someone who simply forgot their password or email address (if it was a throwaway, that's not that difficult to do) and made a new account because it was easier. Moderators have more tools to detect potential fraud, and can escalate to employees if there are enough indicators.

Comment: @Aguestwho'scalledRedd Likewise, if you see the exact same code from your answer on the new question *without attribution*, please flag the question for plagiarism -- per the license used on the site, any code used must be attributed.

Comment: actually not an bad idea when someone really try's to let others do their work. Thanks for you advice in total!