# Question with Bounty (+150) got answered and accepted. After discussion in comments the answer was unaccepted (for no reason))

Tags: discussion, bounty, behavior

After seeing that the question had a 150-reputation points bounty, I put a little effort in the question and extended his code. After one question from the questioner in the comment and my answer, the answer got accepted and his original problem was solved.

After that, the question was edited and in the comment he asked "Now I have that problem. What should I do now?". After helping out a few times, I recommended trying first...After that he thanked me and unaccepted the answer and opened up a new question using my code (which is deleted now, but it showed me he is using that code).

That is the question I am talking about:
*[Make inventory that receives purchased items from the shop system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73337654/make-inventory-that-recieve-purchased-items-from-the-shop-system)*

Am I right feeling "baited" into the question through the bounty or is that a valid thing to do?

As of ~5 or 6 PM UTC (hours after I asked this Meta Q), the answer has been re-accepted by the OP.

Comment: You're possibly a victim of a chameleon question: [What should I do when a user keeps changing their question expecting me to change my answer to match?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387137/2821954)

Comment: FWIW, the bounty is still running for 5 days plus there is a grace period afterwards for awarding the bounty. So they haven't cheated you out of the bounty... yet.

Comment: Also if you have the highest-scored answer with at least 2 score you'll be automatically awarded half the bounty if they don't otherwise pick a winner.

Comment: I'm not sure if the bounty makes it any different, but basically same scenario as [Dealing with questions that are edited after my answer has been accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309237/2745495)

Comment: I would contend that the bounty does not make this situation any different.  It raises the stakes a tad, but it's ultimately the same as any other question.

Comment: I am the questioner. I will give the bounty when my question is solved. And when no one else answers a better answer. I am not using the code since it has problems but i wanted someone else to help me with the errors since you gave up. Helping me. Thank you anyways and you dont need to complain about the bounty. You'll recieve it when the time is right i am not baiting you or anyone. I'm just being patient.

Comment: This isn't just a matter of patience. The edits made 18 hours ago are easily interpreted as moving the goalpost after the question had already received answers, which is frowned upon. That the answers did not really solve the original problem is also a sign that the question was missing some details.

Comment: It seems like my question is covering two different topics which are both answered already. I guess you could call it impatiend, because I interpreted the Bounty Guidelines wrong. Thanks for your answers although it was covered already. Didn't want to struck anybodys nerve here, just clarification.

Comment: For that i was adding details everytime i tried to solve the answer given script. And after the edits he helped 2 times after that he's had enough so i just posted the script with his "little effort" in a new question to get my errors solved not because i'm using it (since it has errors) code still didn't work for me until now and i am not using it.

Comment: Flzzz no worries dude. You will get the bounty i'm working on solving the issues you refered to by looking in google and watching videos. Thanks for the help man i appreciate it.

Comment: The canonical (but does it apply here?): *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/)*